# Using Shell Script to Control another Program

Tags: bash

So I'm new to this, but I want to be able to open this one compiled c program called "program" via my shell script and then have my shell script provide input for the program. In this case I want my shell script to input every number up to one million. I'm not even sure if this code is correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

num=1

while[ num != 1000000 ]
do
  ./program

  #?unsure?

  num++
done
```

The C program simply asks this and then terminates after the first input. (What the program does with the inputs is irrelevant.)

```
Please enter a number:
```

And I want my Shell Script to enter in a number and run the program again and enter a different number until it reaches one million entries.

Comment: you can use the `seq` command to generate numbers. For example `seq 1 1000000` will do what you want

Comment: Can you also include the actual c program as well in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can use `seq` to generate numbers. To have your program read the numbers you can do this using a number of ways. The easiest I can think of is to `echo` the number and pipe that output to your program

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in $(seq 1 1000000); do
  echo $num | ./program
done
```

You can also use [`here-string`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean) in bash to feed the input required:

```
./program <<< "$num"
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this case I want my shell script to input every number up to one million.

You need to fix your bash syntax, but it should be possible to pass the `num` as input for `program`

```
#!/bin/bash

num=1    
while [ $num -lt 1000000 ]
do
  ./program $num      
  num=$((num+1))

done
```

Comment: should it be `./program $num` or something?

Comment: This will only work if the program is reading input from the command line args. If the input is expected via stdin, then a pipe is required or here-string

Comment: The program takes input after "./program" is entered. So "./program 1234" won't work for example.